# Handlebars-loader with inline partials

Tags: handlebars.js, webpack-handlebars-loader

Seems like [handlebars-loader](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader) doesn't handle inline partials as I expected.
I want you use them in the same way as `{{> @partial-block}}`.
Lets say we have index.hbs

```
{{#>wrapper}}
    {{#*inline "column1"}}
        This is test for col 1
    {{/inline}}
    {{#*inline "column2"}}
        This is test for col 2
    {{/inline}}
{{/wrapper}}
{{#>wrapper}}
    {{#*inline "column1"}}
        This is another test for col 1
    {{/inline}}
    {{#*inline "column2"}}
        This is another test for col 2
    {{/inline}}
{{/wrapper}}
```

and wrapper.hbs partial

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column1">
        {{> column1}}
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        {{> column2}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column1">
        <div class="one">
            This is test for col 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
            This is test for col 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column1">
            This is another test for col 1
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
            This is another test for col 2
    </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately loader doesn't handle `{{> column1}}` as inline partial but tries to load a file and obviously fails. 
Can somebody advise? Maybe I want too much...